# Multiple axis to display day and month year with d3 scaleTime

Tags: d3.js

Thanks in advance.I am working with d3.js to create a chart. I want to have two axis on top. one should display month and year and another should display corresponding days for the month and as we zoom both the axis should be narrow down. Like on zoom month should be converted into days and days should be converted into hours. Please refer the below snapshot.
[image]

The box display the no of days and above the boxes it shows month and year.
Point 1 :  So when we zoom in, the days should be converted into the lower dimension which is hours and and month should display with day. Please refer the below snapshot

[image]

Point 2 : If I zomm more deep, it should come like this :

[image]

And if zoom out the scale for days and month should come back to their original form as it was in first snapshot.

My x-axis scale is like this :

```
        const xtimeScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([d3.min(chartdata, function (d) { 
                                return parseTime(d.arrivalTime_data); }),
                           d3.max(chartdata, function (d) { 
                                return parseTime(d.departureTime_data); })
                               ])
                           .range([0, WIDTH - MARGIN.LEFT - MARGIN.RIGHT]);
```

Where "chartdata" is an array of object having structure like this :

```
      {
              arrivalTime_data: "2020-12-19 14:01:26"
              departureTime_data: "2020-12-20 21:02:02"
              imo_data: "9632480"
              serviceName_data: "Service 1"
              short_service_name: "ML - Service"
              vesselName_data: " Ves_Tax"
       }
```

Can anyone please help me in achieving the same functionality. or can provide any fiddle for the same. Thanks

Comment: Can anybody please provide any solution or hint

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you would need to create two scale time x axis and then try zoom functionality.

Check this D3 time series graph- [D3 timeseries graph](https://bl.ocks.org/robyngit/89327a78e22d138cff19c6de7288c1cf)